# Code::Blocks return error when using OpenCV "undefined reference to `cvFree_'|" in C

Tags: c, opencv, gcc

```
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvDecRefData':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvFree_'|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvFree_'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvGetRow':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvGetRows'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvGetCol':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvGetCols'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvReleaseMatND':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvSubS':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvAddS'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvCloneSeq':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvSeqSlice'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvSetNew':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvSetAdd'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvGetSetElem':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvGetSeqElem'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvEllipseBox':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvEllipse'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvFont':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvInitFont'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvReadIntByName':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvGetFileNodeByName'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvReadRealByName':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvGetFileNodeByName'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvReadStringByName':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvGetFileNodeByName'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvReadByName':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvGetFileNodeByName'|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvRead'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvContourPerimeter':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvArcLength'|
/home/piotr/Dokumenty/Projekt antybulglar/main.o||In function `cvCalcHist':|
main.c|| undefined reference to `cvCalcArrHist'|
||=== Build failed: 18 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I,ve tried to install it in many ways for example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqQB5KKJCh0

And still nothing.

Comment: what do you link ? you seem to be missing the opencv libs like -lopencv_core, etc. (and please, use the c++ api instead of the arcane c one)

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed it, I needed to add OpenCV to Code::Blocks in Settings/Compiler there i first add "usr/include/opencv" and "usr/include/opencv2" to Search Directories/Compiler. And add all .so from usr/local/lib for OpenCV in Linker Settings tab.